# How do I sort data from a list and append the the number of occurrences in the list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting

I am having trouble dissecting this data. I would like to find out how many #1 are in each list. After finding that number, I would like to append it to another list for later.

I seem to be getting the input:

```
--> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

When I really want:

```
--> [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 11, 0]
```

This is the code:

```
d = []
count = 0

b = [[1,3,6,2,7,3,9,2,7,1,7], 
     [1,5,8,3,0,3,6,2,7,2,1],
     [1,5,2,6,8,6,2,5,1,8,9],
     [5,2,5,2,1,8,1,5,2,4,6],
     [5,7,2,7,3,7,3,7,3,9,2],
     [1,5,8,3,0,3,6,2,7,2,1],
     [5,2,5,2,1,8,1,5,2,4,6],
     [3,6,1,5,7,8,4,3,6,3,3],
     [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     [3,4,5,6,8,5,7,5,7,3,7]]

for i in b:
    for x in b:
        if x == 1:
            count =+ 1
    d.append(count)
    count = 0

print(d)
```

Comment: I'm assuming the `=+` is a typo and you meant `+=`. You might want to edit the title of this question as it doesn't really have a lot to do with sorting.

Comment: yeh a typo  @AChampion

Comment: Hopefully the answer below helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the wrong object in your second `for` loop, I believe you meant:

```
for x in i:
```

This is why you are getting `0`s

There is a `Counter` class in the standard `collections` module, so you can simplify this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [Counter(i)[1] for i in b]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 11, 0]
```

You can also do this without the `Counter` class a bit more verbosely:

```
>>> [sum(1 for x in i if x == 1) for i in b]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 11, 0]
```

Comment: `[sum(x==1 for x in i) for i in b]` would be shorter, if you don't mind bools being treated as ints automatically.

Comment: @Chrono Kitsune thanks a lot. how did you learn to put so much into so little code? it looked like a lamda function but it's not i think. thanks anyway

Comment: @HeketavNolroc That knowledge is born primarily from exploration -- what is allowed and how to use the language and library to keep things as succinct as possible while still being readable. Surprisingly, `True+True+True == 3` is a true statement, which is the trick to avoiding the `if x==1` at the end of the expression. The rest is pretty straightforward if you understand that list comprehensions are like condensed for loops and generator expressions like the one passed to the `sum` function are iterable like list comprehensions, which is why they can be passed to functions like `sum`.